# PHP - How to logout all logged in users?

Tags: php

I want a method to force logout all logged in users using Php

the session check code goes like this:

```
<?php
include "dbConn.php";
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
   header("location:Login.php");
   die();
}
?>
```

so it depends on the session variable "`$_SESSION['login_user']`" , So is there a way to unset this variable for all the logged in users ?

Regards

Comment: You can delete all the session files, that will destroy all session variables, incluiding the login data. I don't think there's any easy way to be more fine-grained.

Comment: The only possible way to do this is, change the session storage path where you have  write access, and then delete all the files (session storage) in that location to destroy all the session.. That is the only way.

Comment: Another option is to just use a new session key which won't exist for anyone. Define a global constant called `SESSION_USER_KEY` and set it to something with a version number such as `login_user_v1` or something, and use that constant everywhere. If there's a session but that key doesn't exist, destroy the session to cleanup the old stuff.

Comment: could also change the [session name](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment, you could also just change the session key that you are testing. I would recommend making that globally available and assign it a version number that you increment when you want to log everyone out.

Here's a full version that also includes full destruction of the session's data that you may or may not want. This code hasn't been tested but I'm fairly confident it is mostly accurate.

Also, this doesn't "log everyone out", it instead logs everyone out the next time they access the site. For most people this is the same thing, but it is possible that some site's might have a need for the former, and I think the other comments address that instead.

```php
// This should be in a globally available file, and all
// session checks should rely on this
const SESSION_USER_KEY = 'login_user_v1';

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION[SESSION_USER_KEY])) {

    // Only needed if you potentially have additional code before the redirect
    $_SESSION = [];

    // Optionally kill the cookie, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php#example-4744
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );

    session_destroy()
    header("location:Login.php");
    die();
}
```

Comment: Why not a simple header("Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID="");

Comment: Done by itself that would log everyone out always, and presumably they want people to long in again, so I assume you mean inside of the `if`? Although it isn’t wrong to set a cookie using the header function, the cookie name itself is configurable so I’d recommend using that at least. I honestly haven’t dropped a cookie by hand server-side in a long while which is why I lifted that from the manual.