# PHP - Database Sessions , Does it worth it?

Tags: php, database

Currently, I'm working on a small php application and there was a need to logout all logged in users after performing some modification in the settings from the admin panel side , as we know that php store the session files on the server and to logout all logged in users "not immediately, but at least when they refresh the page or access the site next time" I need a way for handling those sessions , either by brutal delete for the session files that are stored in the server `session.save_path` or with a better way like storing the sessions in a database like this example [here](http://www2.hawaii.edu/%7Etakebaya/cent285/session_db_server/session_db_server.html) .

So the traditional session check goes like this for example:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
   header("location:Login.php");
   die();
}
```

If i implemented a database session this will store the session ID , data in a database table and when we want to get some session variable there will be a query to the database to get these data and the same when checking for the session itself if it still valid .

the point is , the database session will imply a **burden** on the database because of the number of queries , so instead of implementing a full database session store i went like this: when the user log in, his session ID will be stored in a table along with his user id and username and when the user navigate through the site and every time visits a new page or refresh the current , a check will be performed (additional to the above code) to see if he has a record in that database and if not he will be logged out :

```
if (!hasValidSession($conn,$_SESSION['user'])) {
   header("location:logout.php");
   die(); 
}
```

As you can see the session data are still in the file system on the server, only a simple check will be performed to check for the session itself instead of fetching everything from the database .

My question , is this approach ok as a way around to logout all users by simple TRUNCATE to the session table or delete sessions related to a specific user to logout that user? or Am I doing a disaster here and I should implement  a full database session in my php application ?

Regards

Comment: Please tell more about "the database session will imply a **burden** on the database because of the number of queries".   How many sessions are you talking about?

Comment: Here’s a way to logout everyone using the file system and a simple constant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73833045/231316

Comment: @Luuk a session per user , the number of users may get very large , and i have no idea how mysql database would perform with this amount of connections for sessions and for data queries .

Comment: @ChrisHaas I saw this solution sir the idea is to change the version number of the key ,  to be honest i never worked with const yet , but would it be globally available to all users ?

Comment: "very large" is a vague term, [100000](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) is not ...

Comment: As noted in that example, you just need to find a way to include the constant’s definition wherever you need it, which would basically be in the single block of code you share across all pages that check for session validity.

Comment: @ChrisHaas maybe I'm missing something  ,but if i want to log everyone out i have to change the key right ? ,but how would you change a const ? i mean this is why they exist because they are not meant to be changed

Comment: It is constant for the lifetime of the HTTP request.

Comment: @Luuk By default 151 is the maximum permitted number of simultaneous client connections in MySQL  as far as i know , wouldn't that be a problem if the number of clients connecting and querying the database was larger than 151 ? or the requests are can be queued ?

Comment: Yes, from the 152'th connection (and more) you will get this error: "ERROR 1040 (HY000): Too many connections"  But it is possible to set a higher number than 151 in your config?